# Cambiar elemento de un Array

Tags: android, array, kotlin

Hola tengo el siguiente Array, como puedo modificar el dato "id" del primer elemento del array, he logrado obtenerlo con exito con `nombre.get(0).Url` esto me imprime "video1.mp4", exactamente lo que le indico, el problema es a la hora de cambiar el dato, he visto algunos tutoriales que lo hacen con `Set, pero en este caso no funciona. COMO HARIA PARA CAMBIAR EL DATO "URL", DEL PRIMER ELEMENTO

```
[
  {
    "Id" : 1,
    "Url" : "video1.mp4",
    "storyThumbUrl" : "imagen1.jpg",
  },
  {
    "Id" : 2,
    "storyUrl" : "video2.mp4",
    "img" : "imagen2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Id" : 3,
    "storyUrl" : "video3.mp4",
    "img" : "imagen3.jpg"
  }
]
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega como lo trataste de obtener, recuerda agrega lo que realizaste en tus preguntas, deseas modificar el json o el archivo, te sugiero agregar detalles, revisa [ask] saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente tienes que asignar el valor tal que así

lista[0].Url = "nuevo valor"

Pero tienes que asegurarte de estar utilizando una lista de tipo mutable.

Espero ayudarte

Comment: Muchísimas gracias enserio, me ayudo mucho